# Can a graph have more then one undirected path between two nodes?

Tags: graph-theory

Can a graph have more then one undirected weighted path between two nodes. See picture below:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikw1l.jpg

Comment: Not with the usual definition, though there are extensions of the usual definition in which that is allowed.

Comment: Could you refer me a source for definition?

Comment: More than one edge, no, as in your picture.  More than one path, yes.

Comment: An extension of the definition of a graph that allows multiple edges is the definition of multigraphs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph. You'll want the second definition of undirected multigraphs.

Comment: Some books will define graphs such that a vertex pair $p,q$ could share multiple edges and say a simple graph is a graph which has none of these double edges and others will define graphs to have none of these double edges but allow for multi-graphs to have these. This question really comes down to what is a graph and for that you need to provide a definition.

Comment: And sometimes we decide that sharing an edge between only two nodes is overly restrictive and we use a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph instead.

Comment: By "path" do you mean *path* or do you mean *edge*? A graph in which every pair of  nodes is joined by a unique path is called a *tree.*